# Self-Mutating `IO a` in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I would like to use `IO Int` to represent a stream of integers by hiding an `IORef` in its definition:

```hs
tickrate :: Int
tickrate = 20000

ioIntTest :: Int -> IO Int
ioIntTest i0 = do
    intRef <- newIORef i0
    f intRef
    where
        f :: IORef Int -> IO Int
        f ref = do
            i <- readIORef ref
            modifyIORef ref (+1)
            return i

ioTest :: Int -> IO ()
ioTest n = do
    let intStream = ioIntTest n
    intStreamToPrint intStream
    where
        intStreamToPrint is = do
            threadDelay tickrate
            c <- is
            putStrLn (show c)
            intStreamToPrint is
```

However, if I call `ioTest n`, rather than seeing an increasing list of numbers printed to the screen, I see only the starting number, `n`, repeating indefinitely.

While I could refactor this code so that incrementing and reading the value of `ioIntTest i0` are done separately, I would like to know if/why the following is impossible:

**Can I make an `IO Int` such that each time it is used in `(>>=)` (either explicitly or implicitly in `do` notation) the returned `Int` mutates?**

While such an `IO Int` is perhaps not referentially transparent, I thought that was the point of wrapping computations in the `IO` monad.

---

Such a refactoring could be:

```hs
tickrate :: Int
tickrate = 20000

ioIntMutate :: IORef Int -> IO Int
ioIntMutate ref = do
    i <- readIORef ref
    modifyIORef ref (+1)
    return i

ioTest :: Int -> IO ()
ioTest n = do
    intStream <- newIORef n
    intStreamToPrint intStream
    where
        intStreamToPrint is = do
            threadDelay tickrate
            c <- ioIntMutate is
            putStrLn (show c)
            intStreamToPrint is
```

In other words, is there any way to replace the line `ioIntMutate is` in the third-to-last line with an `IO Int`?

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Top_level_mutable_state

Comment: You could use a mutable global variable, but to declare that you'll need to use `unsafe` routines. Alternatively, you could craft a `ioIntTest :: Int -> IO (IO Int)` (yes, double `IO`!) to be used as `do f <- ioIntTest 42 ; x1 <- f ; x2 <- f ; ...` where each `xi` is one unit more than the previous one. Would that satisfy your requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `IO (IO Int)` for that. Like this:

```
ioIntTest :: Int -> IO (IO Int)
ioIntTest n = do
    ref <- newIORef n
    pure $ do
        i <- readIORef ref
        writeIORef ref (i+1)
        pure i

ioTest :: Int -> IO ()
ioTest n = do
    intStream <- ioIntTest n
    intStreamToPrint intStream
    where
        intStreamToPrint is = do
            threadDelay tickrate
            c <- is
            putStrLn (show c)
            intStreamToPrint is
```

Note that the only difference between my `ioTest` and your `ioTest` is this line:

```
let intStream = ioIntTest n -- yours
intStream <- ioIntTest n    -- mine
```

And, by the way, this solution is not so contrived. I have used a trick like this before to hide internal implementation details of an async RPC channel; or for another example on Hackage, check out [`once`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.12/docs/Control-Concurrent-Extra.html#v:once). You don't need to know whether that's implemented with `IORef`s or some other trick, and the author can switch tricks as they find better ones.

As a stylistic note, I'd write `ioTest` a little differently. One of these two:

```
ioTest :: Int -> IO ()
ioTest n = do
    intStream <- ioIntTest n
    forever (intStream >>= print >> threadDelay tickrate)

    -- OR

    forever $ do
        intStream >>= print
        threadDelay tickrate
```